# Join on tables where values are not equal

Tags: postgresql, join

I want to join two tables where values match a condition, not where the values are equal to one another. I've looked around, I have ***no*** idea how to do this.

Here's an example:

**Join Table_1 to Table_2 WHERE NUM1 <= NUM3 AND NUM2  >= NUM4;**

```
Table_1:
ID1|NUM1|NUM2
-------------
AAA|1934|1942
BBB|1935|1943
CCC|1939|1944

Table_2:
ID2|NUM3|NUM4
-------------
HHH|1934|1935
GGG|1935|1939
UUU|1939|1942
FFF|1942|1943
PPP|1943|1944

Join_Result:
ID1|NUM1|NUM2|ID2|NUM3|NUM4
---------------------------
AAA|1934|1942|HHH|1934|1935
AAA|1934|1942|GGG|1935|1939
AAA|1934|1942|UUU|1939|1942
BBB|1935|1943|GGG|1935|1939
BBB|1935|1943|UUU|1939|1942
BBB|1935|1943|FFF|1942|1943
CCC|1939|1944|UUU|1939|1942
CCC|1939|1944|FFF|1942|1943
CCC|1939|1944|PPP|1943|1944
```

---

Tried something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO Join_Result
FROM Table_1 A
JOIN Table_2 B
ON NUM1 <= NUM3 AND NUM2>= NUM4;
```

Comment: That sql looks good to me. What's the problem?

Comment: Looks good to me as well. I setup test tables and tried this manually and it got the result you wrote that you expected above.

Comment: Just tried it on my own box as well. 9 results just like the desired results here.

Comment: Oh my God. I wrote it right in the question above, but I wrote it wrong when I was executing it. Hilarious.

Comment: Please leave this though, I answered my question below, I think it will help people.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL above was correct.

```
SELECT * INTO Join_Result
FROM Table_1
JOIN Table_2
ON NUM1 <= NUM3 AND NUM2>= NUM4;
```